# How to augment LoaderState interface in Spartacus?

Tags: typescript, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to augment the `LoaderState` interface which is declared in the `@spartacus/core` library in the `loader-state.ts` file. Specifically I am trying to change the type of the `error` property to my custom type `MyError`.

This is the original interface:

```
export interface LoaderState<T> {
  loading?: boolean;
  error?: boolean;
  success?: boolean;
  value?: T;
}
```

I tried the approach as mentioned in the documentation https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/eaef8c61b6d9477daf75bff9ac1b7eb4/8d44073a8ffc4562a1401fd0467af197.html?locale=en-US&q=augument#loiod3dddec24bd54035a7d4569c5b31d654 :

```
declare module '@spartacus/core' {
  interface LoaderState {
    error?: MyError;
  }
}
```

But it's not working and the property is still treated as boolean. I suspect the problem is because the `LoaderState` is exported not directly, but as part of the `StateUtils` namespace. Is there a way to augment this interface?

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe my answer with a few points:

1. Please make sure, that your augmented module is placed in any file that is imported somewhere in the code.
   If the file is only your augmented model, you can:
   a) import something, even unused in the file
   b) export an empty object.
2. As far as I know, you can not override any type of property in this way. You can still add your new property, eg. `errorContent: MyError`
3. Since `LoaderState` is not exported directly in `"@spartacus/core"` namespace, you should declare a more direct module, where it is placed. In this case, I guess it is `"@spartacus/core/src/state/utils/loader"`

In summary, it should look roughly like this:

`augmented.model.ts`

```
/*a)*/ import { LoaderState } from '@spartacus/core/src/state/utils/loader';

declare module "@spartacus/core/src/state/utils/loader" {
  interface LoaderState<T> {
    errorContent?: MyError;
  }
}

/*b)*/ export {};
```

`index.ts`

```
import './augmented.model';
```